# Ошибка размера родителя при адаптации в CSS

Tags: css, вёрстка

Я задал родителю ширину в 1280px, но при адаптации для маленьких скринов обнаружил, что этот элемент имеет ширину не в 1280px, а около 440. С чем это связано?
css:

```
.registration-form {
    position: relative; 
    height: 100vh; 
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  
  /* Стили для заднего фото */
  .image-background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden; /* Предотвращаем прокручивание контейнера */
  }
  
  .image-background img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center; /* Чтобы изображение было центрировано */
  }
  
  /* Убрать отступы по умолчанию */
  body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }


.Logo{
  position: relative;
  height: 3%;
  width: 3%;
  top: 7%;
  left: -7%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.Slogan{
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  top: 37%;
  left: 10%;
  font-size: 2vw;
}


/* Стили для контейнера с кнопками */
.login-buttons {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column; /* Кнопки будут располагаться вертикально (одна под другой) */
  align-items: center; /* Выравнивание элементов по центру по горизонтали */
  top: 40%;
  left: 65%;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 50%;
  width: 20%; 
}

  
  /* Стили для кнопок */
  .login-button {
    background-color: #0080ff; /* Голубой цвет */
    color: #fff; /* Белый цвет текста */
    width: 100%;
    height: 11.5%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .register-button {
    background-color: #681cff; /* Зеленый цвет */
    color: #fff; /* Белый цвет текста */
    width: 100%;
    height: 11.5%;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }



  .registration-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 24%;
    height: 22%;
    top: 47%;
    left: 75%; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Центрирование по горизонтали и вертикали */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Полупрозрачный черный цвет */
    z-index: 2; /* Закрываем фон, но оставляем кнопки видимыми */
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  }
















/* Очень маленькие экраны (портретная ориентация): ширина до 360px */
@media (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 460px) {

  .Logo{
    position: relative;
    width: 7%;
    height: 7%;
    top: 4%;
    left: 12%;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .Slogan{
    color: white;
    top: -7%;
    left: 24%;
    font-size: 5vw;
    width: 80%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }


  .login-buttons {
    top: 50%;
    left: 16%;
    height: 25%;
    width: 65%;
    font-size: 2.5vh;
    margin-bottom: 9%;
  }

  .login-button {
    width: 80%;
    height: 30%;
    border-radius: 11px;
  }

  .register-button {
    width: 80%;
    height: 30%;
    border-radius: 11px;
  }

  .registration-overlay {
    width: 63%;
    height: 28%;
    top: 59%;
    left: 48.3%;
  }
}
```

Так же хотел спросить, если нужно, чтобы сайт на ультрашироких мониках был по средине, то для родителя лучше задать сразу фиксированую ширину (как я) или лучше 100vw, а потом через медиа для ультрашириков ограничивать?

Answer (score 0):

Вы задали МАКСИМАЛЬНУЮ ШИРИНУ, а не просто ширину, это важное уточнение, укажите родителю

```
width: 100%;
```

либо используйте сразу width вместо max-width

Comment: А в чем разница? Так же хотел спросить, если нужно, чтобы сайт на ультрашироких мониках был по средине, то для родителя лучше задать сразу фиксированую ширину (как я) или лучше 100vw, а потом через медиа для ультрашириков ограничивать?

Comment: @Dream, Разница в том что max-width ограничивает максимальную ширину, но реальное значение уже просчитывается браузером в зависимости от ситуации, если же сразу указать в width нужное значение то оно явно установится и в 100% случаев будет именно таким

Comment: А по поводу адаптива для ультрашириков, то зависит от подхода к вёрстке,
Если практикуете desktop first - не надо усложнять себе жизнь, делайте фиксированную и адаптируйте уже под более маленькие устройства,
Если mobile first то ваш вариант с 100vw имеет место быть

Comment: Спасибо, я думал, что если 1280 указал, то родитель будет на весь экран до тех пор, пока размер экрана не превысит 1280 пикселей.

Comment: Хотел уточнить, Вы посоветовали сделать фиксированую в случае desktop first, однако у меня так же и есть. Я сделал фиксированую в 1280px, но при этом для мелких экранов, как я и говорил, оно обрезается до 440. Если я заменю и поставлю просто width в 1280, то это тоже не поможет, ведь будет прямоугольник, длинной в 1280px. Ну а случай с 100% не подходит, тк я фиксирую родителя сразу